# Cygwin's bash can't run 'net use /user' command?

Tags: windows, bash, networking, cygwin

I run 'net use /user:"Someone" \somewhere', and it works well with cmd.exe.

With the same cmd.exe, run 'bash --login -i' to use the cygwin/bash, and run the same command but I get the error message as follows.

```
System error 67 has occurred.
```

The network name cannot be found.

Why can't I run 'net use /user' command with cygwin/bash?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In cygwin's bash, you need to escape any of those <strike>forward</strike>back slashes, as those are interpreted as escape characters.

try this

`net use /user:"Someone" \\\\server\\share`

or use single quotes, which will pass the argument unchanged

`net use /user:"Someone" '\\server\share'`

Comment: Minor correction: Need to escape backslashes.  \ backslash, / forward slash.

Comment: @shoover  I always forget which is which, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 3):

I have ran into problems attempting to use the /delete switch with net use from bash in windows.  It seems to be something with the way certain windows commands process command line arguments.

I thought I could get around it by launching "net use" from a cmd.exe sub shell, but that too appears to be impacted by the argument processing problem. I found a work around for cmd.exe in quoting but could not seem to find the right quoting to use net use directly for the task.

```
$ cmd "/c net use T: /delete"
```

Answer (score 2):

In MSYS/Git Bash, parameters starting with a forward slash are converted by *POSIX-to-Windows* path conversion
(i.e. `/delete` looks like a path and is converted to `C:\Program Files\Git\delete` or something alike).

There are two solutions to circumvent this conversion:

1. **Double the first slash** to avoid POSIX-to-Windows conversion:

   ```
   net use //user
   # outputs usage of NET USE

   net use T: //delete
   # outputs "T: was deleted successfully."
   ```
2. Use **temporary environment variable `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1`** like so:

   ```
   MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 net use /user
   # outputs usage of NET USE

   MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 net use T: /delete
   # outputs "T: was deleted successfully."
   ```

Source/Explanation: [Bash translates path parameter in Unix format to windows format, need a way to suppress it #577](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/577#issuecomment-166118846)

*Update: Mention MSYS is used for this answer as suggested in comment from [bobbogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470195/bobbogo).*

Comment: No, plain wrong as far as cygwin goes. Cygwin bash is very compatible with normal bash, and will not molest forward slashes (`/`). This comment refers to _msys_ which I never use precisely due to these shenanigans. (Once had a makefile in _msys_ where 5 backslashes (`\ `) weren't enough, and 6 were too many!)

Comment: Take a look at Cygwin's `/usr/bin/start` code, it's interesting: `"$COMSPEC" //c start "${@//&/^&}"`