# Where is documentation for cygwin "net use" command

Tags: network-programming, cygwin

I have looked everywhere for documentation for the `Cygwin` `net use` command, to no avail. I want to include it in a `.bashrc` script but am having headaches due to escape/quoting conventions and the apparent need to use backslashes in this command. If I use forward-slashes in the `net use` command it thinks I'm giving it an invalid option (what is the point of a command designed to work in a Unix-like environment but which accepts options in Windows syntax???).

Once the share is configured, I find I can substitute forward-slashes which is much friendlier from a Unix perspective but if I want to establish a variable for a path prefix which I can use both in `net use` as well as file paths within that share I can't seem to manage it.

Does anybody know where I can find comprehensive reference documentation for this command?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238935/cygwins-bash-cant-run-net-use-user-command

Comment: Not helpful. I already know that, and that's not reference documentation as I requested. Good luck trying to put that syntax into a variable, and then using it later or heaven forbid in an alias. Every time the variable is expanded you run into escape/quoting issues because some backslashes are removed in the variable expansion. I really need a way to use forward slashes in the variable, and then use it in 'net use' if at all possible. I'm hoping there's an option which says "This is the last option, everything after this is literal", like the -- option in Unix.

Comment: Isn't `net use` a Windows command, not part of Cygwin?

Comment: Aha - quite possible. That would explain why docs are so hard to find. You can find the command referenced in Cygwin docs, but never documented. I may have to resort to some function that replaces backslashes with forward slashes and transform my variables between "net use" and subsequent uses. Yuck. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Backslashes are not removed when expanding variables. They might be removed when assigning the variable in the first place, you just have to double them. There's nothing special about forward slashes in Cygwin, they're used as the prefix for options in many Windows commands (except those that have copied Unix style use of hyphen).

Comment: % A=\\\\foobar; echo $A

Comment: As you start to use those variables in subsequent aliases or other variable definitions things go downhill quickly. And yes I know about single and double quotes and how those affect things but life is not always so simple when you have conflicting demands in your quoting expressions. Trying to capture backslashes in variables and then use them in expressions is bad news.

Comment: The nice thing about Cygwin is that, once you've established a share with 'net use', you can use forward slashes instead of backslashes e.g. //host/path and no longer have to be concerned with escapes. But you have to say \\host\path to 'net use', unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Windows* `net use` command is documented here: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx

Other `net` subcommands are here: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_subcmds.mspx